# HIde div contents after i first logged in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have one div on my web page.

I want to hide it when I first log in but after every reload of the page that div should be opened.

I want to do this using jquery.

```
<div class="expandable">
      <li class="menu"><span>Dispute</span>
</div>
```

Comment: you can hide the div using jquery method i.e $(".expandable").hide(), but when you reload the page that div will be show again. For that you have to use cookies to save the user authentication value on client side and when page is reloaded, it checks the cookie in javascript and then hide or show the div.

Comment: manage one field in db, manage it to flagged true after logged once, when this results true / 1, show your div else nop

Comment: Your HTML is wrong, besides, what do you mean by log in? Are you maintaining a user session or you just want to hide it first time you land on a page and show it the second time?

Answer (score 0):

Write this code in your file when you have successfully login 
You can write this code or function after user login in function

```
 $(".expandable").hide();
```

Comment: that code works for only hiding the div, 'Suraj Chougule' requirement is to hide div on page reload if user is logged in.

Comment: When user first login in it maintain session, so this hide div only when user login and opened when page reload

Comment: plz mention the session maintenance code, because your code is just hiding the div!

Comment: I need to know which server side language it using for session maintenace

Answer (score 0):

You need to use cookie or sessions for this.

The cookie will be checked if they exist on the system every time the site is visited, if they are already set, show the div. These will be set on the first login, so that for every visit after that it will be already there thus showing the div.

If you need it with logged in user, you should use session, following same logic as above. Setting a value in session and checking if it exists before displaying the div.

**Example code to set cookie:**

```
$.cookie("Show", 1, {
  path    : '/',          //The value of the path attribute of the cookie 
                       //(default: path of page that created the cookie).

 domain  : 'yourdomain.com',  //The value of the domain attribute of the cookie
                       //(default: domain of page that created the cookie).

 secure  : true          //If set to true the secure attribute of the cookie
                       //will be set and the cookie transmission will
                       //require a secure protocol (defaults to false).
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can hide the div in css by using  `display:none`and after loading the page try jquery function like  `show(),fadeIn(), or toggle()'